# how to insert data in database before session timeouts within given time limit using java?

Tags: java, session, session-timeout

If I am mentioning the session timeout in descriptor page

```
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

Before terminating session I want to do insert operation in database. Is there any possibility for insertion. I have a thought that when user logins the page and I can use trigger to insert the data for 30 minutes. But if anyone else changes to -1 or more than 30 mins without noticing the trigger is running when user logins at that case what can I do for it?

Answer (score 3):

The remaining time for a session timeout changes every time the client makes interaction, so timing this for 30 minutes is a wrong solution.

Instead use an [HttpSessionListener](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html). A registered `HttpSessionListener` is called every time an HTTP session is created or destoryed (invalidated). This does not depend on the configured session timeout. The `sessionDestroyed()` method is always called right before a session is invalidated and discarded.

```
public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {}

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        // Here session is destoryed.
        // You can insert data to your database here.
        // You can access the session like this:
        HttpSession sess = se.getSession();
    }
}
```

Here is how you can register your `HttpSessionListener` it in your `web.xml`:

```
<web-app>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.dummy.MySessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```