# Spring security save user login/logout date in database and handling session timeouts

Tags: database, spring, session, logout

I need to monitoring users login/logout. SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler works only if the user use the logout button, but I need to store session timeout logouts too. But SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler does not works in this case. From HttpSessionEventPublisher I can catch session timeouts, but I cant get username to store logout date to database. Any elegant solution to handle simple and session timeout logouts?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use auto logout if no activity for some specified time. And store the time when session expires for the user if user is not terminating session manually by logout.

The session timeout in a web application can be configurable in two ways

1) Timeout in the deployment descriptor (web.xml)
– Specified the timeout value in “minute” , enclose with “session-config” element.

```
<web-app ...>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

The above setting is apply for the entire web application, and session will be kill by container if client doesn’t make any request after 20 minutes.

2) Timeout with setMaxInactiveInterval()
– You can manually specified the timeout value in “second” for a particular session.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(20*60);
```

The above setting is only apply on session which call the “setMaxInactiveInterval()” method, and session will be kill by container if client doesn’t make any request after 20 minutes.

Comment: The session-timeout is set. That is not problem. If a user is log in/out i need to store the time when he logged in/out. On simple log in/out I can make it, but when session expired I do not know how to do that, because I need a username or useId to do that. if I use HttpSessionEventPublisher I cant do that, because the session is invalid.

Comment: Implment and overide sessionDestroyed() of Interface HttpSessionListener http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25241852/how-to-insert-data-in-database-before-session-timeouts-within-given-time-limit-u

Comment: I tried it. The session is destroy I cant get the attribute set in the session, so I cant insert into database without any id or username which I like to store in session.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is SessionDestroyedEvent.